# How do I get iTunes to just play one album?

Tags: itunes, music, album

I'm new to iTunes and I was wondering how I get it to play just one album? At present I have "Grid" view enabled. I select the artist I feel like listening to, and it switches to Album by Artist view (songs and artwork).

I double click on the album and it plays through, but then it continues down and plays the next album by the artist... Quite annoying!

How can I get iTunes to just play the album I've told it to?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Both OSX and Windows. Does it make a difference?

Comment: If the answer involves AppleScript, yes, it does. If the answer involves a difference in the way the two platforms work, then yes, it does. In general, it's helpful to specify. In this case, there's an answer that works for both, which is great, but not all solutions work for iTunes on both platforms (just like the version of iTunes can also matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather easier than these solutions. Click the icon view beside the search and select the *Albums* tab at the top so the icons show albums rather than Artists or Composers. Then when you hover over an album you can click "Play Album" to play it. You can also double click the album to see all the songs making sure they are ordered by song number (if necessary).

[image: Fuck Robert Palmer, Fuck Rock and Roll]

This way you can also by command or shift clicking select multiple albums.

Or you can show with the second icon ordered by album by artist. In this view an artist search will help:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I know there's an Album button, I meant to go from Artist > Album. I can't remember the name of every album, but I can always remember the artist :)

Answer (score 4):

You can go to the menu bar and select **View** » **Column Browser** » **Show Column Browser**. Then you can pick an Album in the third column, and only songs on that album will appear in the iTunes window. Note that this will switch you from the *Grid* view to the *List* view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. It's a shame that this is the only way to do it. I much prefer the Zune software's interface in this regard. Ah, Apple. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

While in *List view* you could:

- If using **Play Random Song**, just search for the name of the album, and play. Unless you clear the search box, the played songs will be the ones from the search.
- If you're not using it, just order the list by **Album** and play the first song. The rest of the album will play afterwards.

You could, too, create a new **PlayList**, drag all the songs from that album, and play.